# SSL on JBoss and nginx

Tags: nginx, jboss

I've got an application that runs on JBoss server. Also I've got nginx as reverse proxy server for this application. Now I want to configure ssl. Do I have to configure it on both servers? JKS for JBoss and crt, key for nginx?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. I'm assuming, that nginx serves (and proxies) ports 80 and 443 to JBoss. For this alone, setting um SSL in nginx is sufficient.

If JBoss needs to serve a different port via SSL *directly*, without nginx proxying, to handle your application needs, (e.g. 8443) then you need to setup SSL in JBoss too.